# How to return the object i have called the method with?

Tags: java

For example if I create a new object a and call the method a.compare(k), if a.speed is greater than b how to return a?

```
public Computer compare (Computer k) {

    if(k.getSpeed()>this.speed)
        return k;
    else
    {
        //I need to return the other object that I'm comparing k with
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `return this;`?

Comment: Yes! thank you so much . I'm new at programming  so many concepts are hard to grasp...

Comment: why not `return k.getSpeed()>this.speed ? k : this;`

Comment: @Deadpool that ternary operator is a good idea, but not practical for a new programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an instance method, you are just comparing another Computer with the current Computer, so if you want to return the current computer, return this.